# How to find where a web part has been placed

Tags: web-part

I have a task where I need to locate every page that has a particular web part on it.

It looks like I may be able to get this info from the database itself but I'm not sure how thorough this may be. Is there a better method for doing this?

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 1):

Answer can be found from Stackexchange, here's copy & link to the answer. You can create a simple console application that you run on the server.

"If you'd like to find all Content Query web parts then you would call my code like this:

```
FindWebPart("http://server.com/", "Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart");
```

Here's the code:

```
public static void FindWebPart(string siteCollectionUrl, string webPartName)
{
    using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite(siteCollectionUrl))
    {
        using (SPWeb rootSite = siteCollection.OpenWeb())
        {
            FindWebPartHelper(rootSite, webPartName);
        }
    }
}

public static void FindWebPartHelper(SPWeb site, string webPartName)
{
    // Search for web part in Pages document library
    SPList pagesList = null;
    try
    {
        pagesList = site.Lists["Pages"];
    }
    catch (ArgumentException)
    {
        // List not found
    }

    if (null != pagesList)
    {
        SPListItemCollection pages = pagesList.Items;
        foreach (SPListItem page in pages)
        {
            SPFile file = page.File;
            using (SPLimitedWebPartManager mgr = file.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared))
            {
                try
                {
                    SPLimitedWebPartCollection webparts = mgr.WebParts;
                    foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart wp in webparts)
                    {
                        // Here perform the webpart check
                        // For instance you could identify the web part by
                        // its class name

                        if (webPartName == wp.GetType().ToString())
                        {
                            // Found a match! Now do something...
                            Console.WriteLine("Found web part!");
                        }
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    // Needs to be disposed
                    mgr.Web.Dispose();
                }

            }
        }
    }

    // Check sub sites
    SPWebCollection subSites = site.Webs;
    foreach (SPWeb subSite in subSites)
    {
        try
        {
            FindWebPartHelper(subSite, webPartName);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Don't forget to dispose!
            subSite.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you can make little changes to this code. Currently it does a string comparison, but it's easy to do it in a more typed way."

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633633/sharepoint-how-can-i-find-all-the-pages-that-host-a-particular-web-part)

Answer (score 0):

You can use SPLimitedWebPartManager to get information about the WebPart location and metadata.

For example you can iterate all the pages and use this method to find your WebPart:

```
public static void AddWebPartToPage(SPWeb web, string pageUrl, string webPartName)
    {
        using (SPLimitedWebPartManager webPartManager = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager(pageUrl, PersonalizationScope.Shared))
        {
            SPLimitedWebPartCollection coll = webPartManager.WebParts;
            foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart webpart in coll)
            {
                if (webPartName == webpart.GetType().Name)
                {
                    //your logic here
                }

            }
        }
    }
```